# Feing client authentication with oauth2 Eureka load balancer

Tags: spring-boot, load-balancing, spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud-netflix

Im using oath2 registered in Eureka with 2 machines, for resouce exists a parameter like loadbalanced true

```
spring: 
  oauth2: 
    resource: 
      loadBalanced: true 
      userInfoUri: http:// oauth2/uaa/user
```

Question is it possible use a load balance for client?
example

```
spring: 
  oauth2: 
    sso: 
      home: 
        secure: true 
        path: /,/**/*.html 
    client: 
      accessTokenUri: http://. localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/token 
      userAuthorizationUri: http://. localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/authorize 
      clientId: edge 
      clientSecret: secret
```

Today im using a resquest interceptor for gets a loadbalanced uri, will spring release something like this?